# Does python have a file opening mode which combines the features of "w+" and "r"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-read

I have a script which I use for requesting data from an external API. My script contains complex logic and describing it will take much time. At a certain point of my script I need to open a file, loop over it and and extract each value from it.

```
with open(os.path.abspath("/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/forecast/endpoints/leagueIdExtracted.txt"), "r+") as leagueIdExtracted:
    print("Check is file {} was opened".format(leagueIdExtracted))                                                        
    for id in leagueIdExtracted:
        print("ID {} from opened file".format(id))                 
        savedLeagues.add(int(str(id[:-1])))                 
        print("League IDs {} from file which contain alredy requested IDs".format(savedLeagues))
```

But sometimes isn't up to me file which i open in above isn't exist

```
with open(os.path.abspath("/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/forecast/endpoints/leagueIdExtracted.txt"), "r+") as leagueIdExtracted:
```

Because of it while I open this file I have to open it in `"w+"` mode. Opening it in `"w+"` guarantees that a non-existing file will be created and opened. But while my script opened the file in `"w+"` mode it can't extract values from it.

```
for id in leagueIdExtracted:
    print("ID {} from opened file".format(id))                 
    savedLeagues.add(int(str(id[:-1])))
```

Because of it I have to manually switch between `"w+"` and `"r"` modes. Can anyone advise me whether Python has a mode which will create file while opening it if it does not exist as `"w+"` mode and also allow to extract data as 
`"r"` mode?

Comment: why don't you just seek to the beginning of the file?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what you mean ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot, `w+` is truncating the file, this is the problem, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `a+` as a mode. Using `a+` opens a file for both appending and reading. If the file doesn't exist, it will be created.

```py
# In this example, sample.txt does NOT exist yet
with open("sample.txt", "a+") as f:
    print("Data in the file: ", f.read())
    f.write("wrote a line")
print("Closed the file")

with open("sample.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.seek(0)
    print("New data in the file:", f.read())
```

Output:

```
Data in the file:
Closed the file
New data in the file: wrote a line
```

You should keep in mind that opening in `a+` mode will place the cursor at the *end* of the file. So if you want to read data from the beginning, you will have to use `f.seek(0)` to place the cursor at the start of the file.

Comment: I checked your suggetion. You are right "a+" mode create isn't existed file but didn't allow to loop and extract from it. Try to reproduce my script

Comment: The last part of my answer explains why that happens. When using `a+`, the cursor is placed at the end of the file. Attempting to read immediately after opening will give you nothing. You have to move the cursor to the beginning of the file with `f.seek(0)`

Comment: thank you man for new knowledge. I checked it and it's properly work. Thank you for solution. I will flag your answer as right and if you can vote for my question

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `'r+'` if your objective is to read/write to existing files. In case you want to create new file as well, use `'a+'`. In other words you will be able to do all of the follwing three.

```
1. Create if file does not exist
2. Write (append) if file exists
3. Read in file
```

Quoting from [Reading and Writing Files: Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> - `'r'` when the file will only be read,
> - `'w'` for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased),
> - `'a'` opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end.
> - `'r+'` opens the file for both reading and writing.

Comment: `r+` will not create the file if it doesn't exist

Comment: I was tried "r+" mode but itsn't solve my problem i just checked it ((

Comment: Here is Traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/forecast/team.py", line 17, in <module>
    with open(os.path.abspath("/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/forecast/endpoints/leagueIdExtracted.txt"), "r+") as leagueIdExtracted:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/forecast/endpoints/leagueIdExtracted.txt'

Comment: Actually, I missed the last part of your question. Since you need to create or write to the end (append) it has to be `'a+'` instead of `'r+'`.